# Send error log using ACRA android - Google Docs error while sending

Tags: android, logcat

I know it's hard to make a error free application but still i'm trying to make with less defects at least.

1. So when i googled i came to know we can ACRA can be used to send
   errors of Crashed applications.

   [ACRA Basic Setup](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)

   I tried to throw my own user defined exception. I'm getting following error.

> 11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625): Failed to send crash report for
>   1320379577000-approved.stacktrace 11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):
>   org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending report to
>   Google Form. 11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):     at
>   org.acra.sender.GoogleFormSender.send(GoogleFormSender.java:64) 11-04
>   09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):    at
>   org.acra.ErrorReporter.sendCrashReport(ErrorReporter.java:850) 11-04
>   09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):    at
>   org.acra.ErrorReporter.checkAndSendReports(ErrorReporter.java:960)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.acra.ErrorReporter$ReportsSenderWorker.run(ErrorReporter.java:142)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625): Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out 11-04 09:36:25.896:
>   E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native
>   Method) 11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:788)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   11-04 09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.acra.util.HttpRequest.sendPost(HttpRequest.java:109) 11-04
>   09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):    at
>   org.acra.util.HttpRequest.sendPost(HttpRequest.java:80) 11-04
>   09:36:25.896: E/ACRA(625):    at
>   org.acra.util.HttpUtils.doPost(HttpUtils.java:59) 11-04 09:36:25.896:
>   E/ACRA(625):  at
>   org.acra.sender.GoogleFormSender.send(GoogleFormSender.java:62)

I guess i have made some mistake in form..  but cannot spot what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get better answers on the ACRA mailing list.

Sending the logcat definitely works, but you might not want to add that permission in a production app, it may scare people away. Did you use a Google Docs form for the report? If so, the logcat will be in the  LOGCAT column. Details are [here](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#Adding_logcat,_eventlog_or_radiolog_extracts_to_reports).

Comment: Hi Nikolay, i have checkedt there. Also i used Google Docs only intially. I was good but i'm getting only crashed app details. If i need error logs in Google docs wat i need to do. I donno to add logcat to report. I even checked that link. give some example which will be easier to understand

Comment: Follow the Wiki instructions: add a formKey, add necessary permissions (including `READ_LOGS`), simulate a crash (uncaught exception). You might also try adding the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, but that shouldn't be necessary for the logcat.

Comment: I guess i was not clear in my ques. i wanna get logcat detail even when there is no exception. i mean even when there is no "FORCE CLOSE".

Comment: i have donw with FormKey. i got all the reports in my GoogleDocs when my app crashed. I succeded in that. but i need GoogleDocs to be updated by logcat details even when there is no crash. is it possible to achieve?

Comment: `ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleSilentException(caughtException)` will probably work. Read the Wiki and the docs, it's all there. If it doesn't work as expected, post on the official list.

Comment: Nickolay thanks i succeded as you said.. but i face some other problem. can you help me in the above edited one

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should create a new question. It's a read timeout, so looks like a network problem.

Comment: I used `ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleSilentException(null);` Is there a way to tell when the logcat is uploaded ? Right now the user presses the button in my app to send the logcat but has no way of knowing that it *really* happened.

Comment: No. If there is no network connection, the report will be saved and send when the device is connected. What matters is that it will be sent eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Change timeout manually:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", socketTimeout = 30000)
```